# Identify board game played as a child featuring cute monsters

Tags: identify-this-game

When I was a child I had a board game that featured small plastic monsters. If I recall each player chose a type of monster and you got three monsters to play with of that type.

I remember nothing of the game play apart from I that I think you could chose which of your monsters you moved in your turn.

There were Blue, Yellow, Red and Green Monsters I remember the Blue monsters where like lumpy blue clouds on legs with a bulbous nose and one of the other colours was triangle shaped with an eye on two of the three sides of the triangles.

A friend asked me what the game was called recently and though I remember playing it I can't for the life of me remember what it was called.

Answer (score 8):

I found it, the game was called The Gunge Game and was released in 1989 by Waddingtons. It doesn't even have a wikipedia entry.

[image]

Comment: More surprising, it's not on boardgamegeek

Comment: @ikegami As of 2020.01 11, it is listed on BoardGameGeek. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/158132/gunge-game